# Pouchdb replicate from couchdb takes huge time nearly 30min, for record of 3000 docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, couchdb, pouchdb

```
   localDb.replicate.from(remoteDb).then((response) => {
      console.log('response.status',response.status)
})
```

here I tried to replicate localdb(pouchdb) from remotedb(couchdb), it does the desire work but it takes huge time nearly 30 mins

Comment: There are many things that could make this slow. Network speed, disk speed, document size. You haven't provided any information to help diagnose.

Comment: as it also replicates deleted records also, which are 90000 right now, but it will go increasing, so how to avoid them

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid replicating deleted records?

Comment: yes, got it by,   selector: {
                    _deleted: {
                      $exists: false
                    }
                  }

Comment: Be careful when skipping deleted documents--it means that anything deleted on the source will never become deleted on your PouchDB instance.

Comment: thanks, buddy, I haven't thought about it